# React-router error - 'Cannot call method 'getRouteAtDepth' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I am trying to implement react-router on an my app. My main file contains the following code:

```
'use strict';

import 'babel/polyfill';
import React from 'react/addons';
import App from './components/App';
import ContentPage from './components/ContentPage';
import Dispatcher from './core/Dispatcher';
import AppActions from './actions/AppActions';
import Router from 'react-router';

var { Route, RouteHandler, Link } = Router;

function run() {

  var routes = (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
      <Route handler={ContentPage}/>
    </Route>
  );

  Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
    React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
  });

}
```

Inside my **App** component I have this code:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <RouteHandler />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This code generates the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'getRouteAtDepth' of undefined
   at RouteHandler.createChildRouteHandler
```

If I change `<RouteHandler />` to be directly `<ContentPage />`, the code works. 
Any idea what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:
Apparently, I was using "[React starter kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit)", which renders the "App" component on server as well. When adding react-router to that component, this (server side) error accrued.

I did not need server side rendering on my project, so removing this solved my problem. I will try to investigate why this happened later when I have time.

Comment: What version of React are you using?

Comment: react version: "0.13.0", react-router:  "0.13.2"

Comment: What about this: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/720

Comment: Thanks, but it seems react is only loaded one, so it is probably not the issue...

Comment: @YanivEfraim, I got the exact same error. I tried replacing all require('react') references within react-router with require('react/addons') - but it still gave me the same error. In the end, it turned out to be an issue with my gulp file! I was using browserify(..).externals(libs), and the 'libs' array had 'react' instead of 'react/router'.

Answer (score 0):

Try move your `router` into `App` component module something like this:

```
var React = require('react'),
    Router = require('react-router'),
    Route = Router.Route,
    RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler,
    ContentPage = require('./components/ContentPage'),
    App, routes;

App = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
         return (
              <div className="App">
                  <RouteHandler />
              </div>
         );
    }
});

routes = (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
        <Route handler={ContentPage}/>
    </Route>
);

module.exports = {
    run: function () {
        Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
            React.render(<Handler/>, document.body)
        });
    }
};
```

and appropriate your `run` module will seems like this:

```
 var AppRunner = require('./component/App');
 AppRunner.run();
```

Just refactor this in your ES6 way, I hope it'll help you.